# How to set a multi user Jupyterlab server with Jupyterhub from a server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I followed a tutorial to install and launch jupyterhub in my server and use it in my local machine. But, with my actual config file I can't access to my jupyterlab in my local machine.
Here is my current config file :

```
c.LocalAuthenticator.create_system_users = True
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'jupyter'}
c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.JupyterHub.hub_port = 54321
```

Basically, with this conf, I'm able to access to jupyterlab in my local machine with https:[IP_ADRESS_OF_SERVER]:54321
But if it's not working, I think i'm doing something wrong or misunderstading.

Anyone can debug me pls?